# Python: how to install dsx_core_utils package

Tags: python, db2, data-science-experience

I'm trying to adapt the code snippets presented on the following page:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/watson-studio-local/1.2.1?topic=data-write-sources

However, I don't understand where to get the *dsx_core_utils* package at the beginning and how to install it.
If I didn't miss anything, nothing is, unfortunately, documented on the IBM homepage and google only delivers a few results all redirecting to the IBM homepage.

Does anybody know if this package was moved or renamed etc.? Or maybe knows another package that would accomplish the tasks that the original package is used for?

Comment: What is the intent of adapting the snippets? That DSX is out of service at this point, but some of the underlying intent isn't.  What version of the tools are you working against now? - eg https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-data/4.0?topic=notebook-using-watson-studio-lib replaces a lot of dsx_core_utils - is that what you wanted?  (I can make an answer if that's the intent of the question)

Answer (score 1):

That package is pre-installed in the notebook runtimes of Watson Studio, as part of IBM Cloud Pack for Data. It is not available separately. Furthermore, it is a legacy API that should not be used for new code.

In the latest product versions, the replacement is ibm_watson_studio_lib. In older product versions, and in Cloud Pack for Data as a Service (our Cloud offering), the replacement is project_lib. These packages are also pre-installed where applicable. Please refer to the product documentation for instructions how to use them.

As of 2022-01, none of these packages are available separately from the products I mentioned.